# function invocation in react render

Tags: reactjs

just wondering how often do you guys use construction like this.

```
class Cmp extends React.Component {
 constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.handler = this.handler.bind(this)
 }
 handler(x) {
  return () => console.log(`${x}, i am not immediately called`)
 } 

 render() {
  return(
    <div>
     <div onClick={this.handler('hey')}
    </div>
  )
 }
}
```

1. i'm not using arrow function because each time component mounts, it leads to re-binding functions in constructor
2. i' not using fat arrow in render because each render will create a new function
3. im' not using binding in render because it will lead to re-binding each render
4. i'm using carrying in normal function to do the trick with prevent self auto calling in render

and the question is, - in what universe am i right?

Comment: In this universe you're wrong regardless, because you forgot to close your inner `div` element.

Comment: haha well said..

Answer (score 2):

This is way to do it but one more elegant solution than this is you can use `babel-preset-stage-0`.Using this you don't have to write the binding in the constructor.Your program then will become

```
class Cmp extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }

    //This will bind automatically
    handler = (x) => {
        return () => console.log(`${x}, i am not immediately called`)
    } 

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <div onClick={this.handler('hey')}></div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

So if you have many function defined then it comes handy.

Answer (score 2):

> i'm not using arrow function because each time component mounts, it
>   leads to re-binding functions in constructor

Well, that's just the cost of creating an object. The same would happen for a "regular function" bound in the constructor.

> i' not using fat arrow in render because each render will create a new
>   function

But you are returning new function on every render anyway :) Component re-renders and calls `handler` which returns new function and pass it as a prop.

> im' not using binding in render because it will lead to re-binding
>   each render

The same as above.

Not sure what 4 means.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be doing something like this:

```
class Cmp extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handler = this.handler.bind(this)
    }
    handler = (x) => {
        return (console.log(`${x}, i am not immediately called`))
    }

    render() {
        return ( 
            <div>
                <div onClick = {()=>{this.handler('hey')}}> </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

and the points which you have mentioned are something which is the core of react and if you want to create a react application then you will have to do this.